# Master-Detail GridView and DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to develop a web application that provides its users with short quizzes. I am trying to follow and utilize the explained example in ASP.NET website that is about Quiz Engine. I have a Master-Details in the result page where when the user selects one of his answered quesitons in the GridView, the details of that question will be displayed in the DetailsView underneath the GridView. Everything works fine.

**What I want now is just making the DetailsView (which is the details of the answered question) hidden unless the user selects one of the answered questions. So how to do that?**

Also, it will be very good if I this DetailsView will be diplayed using Ajax instead of PostBack.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="resultGrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" SelectedIndex="0" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="555px">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="Question" />
                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" />--%>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserAnswer" HeaderText="Your Answer" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" />
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="boldtext" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [QuestionID], [QuestionOrder], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuizID] FROM [Question] WHERE ([QuizID] = @QuizID) ORDER BY [QuestionOrder]">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="QuizID" SessionField="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="answerDetails" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                        GridLines="None" Height="45px" Width="552px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="QuestionID">

                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" />
                        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="boldtext" Width="100px" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
                                SortExpression="Question" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer1" HeaderText="A" 
                                SortExpression="Answer1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer2" HeaderText="B" 
                                SortExpression="Answer2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer3" HeaderText="C" 
                                SortExpression="Answer3" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer4" HeaderText="D" 
                                SortExpression="Answer4" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" 
                                SortExpression="CorrectAnswer" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightgreen" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerExplanation" HeaderText="Explanation" 
                                SortExpression="AnswerExplanation" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightgreen" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DetailsView>                
                </td>
            </tr>
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

The Code-Behind that I have is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        if (al == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }

        resultGrid.DataSource = al;
        resultGrid.DataBind();

        // Save the results into the database.
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // Calculate score
            double questions = al.Count;
            double correct = 0.0;


            for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer a = (Answer)al[i];
                if (a.Result == Answer.ResultValue.Correct)
                    correct++;
            }

            double score = (correct / questions) * 100;
            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Replace("ARAMCO\\", "");
            SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ToString();
            userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @Username)";

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("QuizID", Session["QuizID"].ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            // "N4" is for displaying four decimal places, regardless of what the value is 
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString("N4"));

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Username", username);

            int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                // Let's just notify that the insertion didn't
                // work, but let' s continue on ...
                errorLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your quiz results into our database.  Therefore, the results from this quiz will not be displayed on the list on the main menu.";


            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to update the SqlDataSource1 inorder to take its parameter's value from the GridView so that unless the user select a row in the GridView the detailsView will not appear. Try this.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString=" 
   <%$ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [QuestionID], 
  [QuestionOrder], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuizID] FROM 
   [Question] WHERE ([QuestionID] = @QuestionID) ORDER BY [QuestionOrder]">
                    <SelectParameters>
                       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="resultGrid" Name="QuestionID" 
                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you gave it to me but it did work with me. The DetailsView is disappeared but when I click on the select besides one of the answered questions, nothing was displayed. What I want is to show the DetailsView when I clicked on the select. HOW TO DO THAT?

Comment: Exactly that is what I suggested when you select the gridView row it should display.Have you seen the way I edited the select command above "WHERE ([QuestionID] = @QuestionID)" copy the code as it is and try. It should work as far as DataKeyNames="QuestionID" in the resulGrid

Comment: By the way check the select button you are using. Post it if possible

Comment: I copied your answer as it is but still when I clicked in the select button, nothing was appeared. I put a snapshot for the GridView that I got.

Comment: Try to use another data source control for the gridview and avoid using code behind, you may figure out the problem.